# Is it possible to do pattern matching with given value in SML?

Tags: pattern-matching, sml

In Scala it is possible, so I wonder if this possible in SML as well, consider such code:

```
fun in_list(elem,coll) =   
  case coll of
      [] => false
    | elem :: tail => true
    | head :: tail => in_list(elem,tail);
```

In the second line of `case` I would like to use `elem` from the arguments, but SML treats it as a placeholder and throw an error on redundant case (the third line).

So -- is it possible to use `elem` here and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You'll have to use an `if`:

```
fun in_list(elem,coll) =   
  case coll of
      [] => false
    | head :: tail =>
        if head = elem
        then true
        else in_list(elem,tail)
```

Or, in this case, you could also use logical operators instead of an `if`:

```
fun in_list(elem,coll) =   
  case coll of
      [] => false
    | head :: tail =>
        head = elem orelse in_list(elem,tail)
```

Comment: Thank you! Pity though, it feels like half-powerful pattern matching :-)